# What is parametric equations of a locus of a fixed point of a circle rolling along a ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, locus, cycloid

I have learnt about cycloids and have a related question:

> What is parametric equation of a locus of a fixed point of a circle
>   rolling along an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Have you looked around the MSE for any similar questions? There isn't just one...

Comment: The length $L$ of an ellipse is $L\approx 2\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$ and your curve probably it will cover the entire region between the two ellipses of axes $ a, b $ and $ a + 2r, b + 2r $ ($r=$ radius of the circle) because the quotient $\dfrac {L} {2\pi r}$ is in general irrational. It would be interesting a case where this quotient is an integer in which case there would be a nice curve.

Comment: Rotation of rolling circle of radius $a$  is rolled ellipse contact length ( expressed in elliptic integrals from ends of,say major axis)  divided by $a$. Calculated rotated components have to be added on to ellipse coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Using clockwise convention,

\begin{align}
  z &= a\sin \theta+bi\cos \theta  \tag{ellipse contact} \\
  n &= \frac{iz'}{|z'|}  \tag{unit normal vector} \\
  &= \frac{b\sin \theta+ai\cos \theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2 \theta+b^2\sin^2 \theta}} \\
  e &= \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a} \\
  s &= a\int_{0}^{\theta} \sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta  \tag{arc length} \\
  &= aE(\theta,e) \\
  c &= z+rn  \tag{centre of circle} \\
  \frac{z-c}{w-c} &= e^{is/r}  \tag{angle rolled by circle} \\
  w &= c+(z-c) e^{-is/r}  \tag{required locus} \\
  &= z+r(1-e^{-is/r})n
\end{align}